# Display error when I set language to 'Malaysia' in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

`I/flutter ( 4941): The getter 'openAppDrawerTooltip' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4941): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 4941): Tried calling: openAppDrawerTooltip
I/flutter ( 4941): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'openAppDrawerTooltip' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4941): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'signedInLabel' was called on null.`

Why I got this error when I switch to Malay?

My supported language is this

```
`static Iterable<Locale> get supportedLocales => [
    const Locale('en', 'US'),
    const Locale('ms', 'MY'),
    const Locale('zh', 'CN'),
];`
```

Comment: cross-ref https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malasia is not yet supported

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/286cdf43f018583e84ded36e0eb26211db6bdd3f/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/material_localizations.dart#L42-L65

Supported languages are

> ```
> ///   * ar - Arabic
> ///   * de - German
> ///   * en - English
> ///   * es - Spanish
> ///   * fa - Farsi
> ///   * fr - French
> ///   * he - Hebrew
> ///   * id - Indonesian
> ///   * it - Italian
> ///   * ja - Japanese
> ///   * ko - Korean
> ///   * ms - Malay
> ///   * nl - Dutch
> ///   * no - Norwegian
> ///   * pl - Polish
> ///   * ps - Pashto
> ///   * pt - Portuguese
> ///   * ro - Romanian
> ///   * ru - Russian
> ///   * th - Thai
> ///   * tr - Turkish
> ///   * ur - Urdu
> ///   * vi - Vietnamese
> ///   * zh - Simplified Chinese
> ```

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/12645 shows an example how to add custom localizations

> ```
> class PolishLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
>   const PolishLocalizationsDelegate();
>
>   @override
>   bool isSupported(Locale locale) => locale.languageCode == 'pl';
>
>   @override
>   Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) => MyPolishMaterialLocalizations.load(locale);
>
>   @override
>   bool shouldReload(PolishLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
> }
> ```

> ```
> new MaterialApp(
>   localizationsDelegates: [
>     const PolishLocalizationsDelegate(),
>     GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
>     GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
>   ],
>   supportedLocales: [
>     const Locale('pl', 'PL'),
>     // .. the other supported locales here
>   ]
> )
> ```